# How can I get current opened window in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I want to get the current opened Window object.
such as in demo.js

```
console.info("=====current_window=====")
console.info(Ti.UI.currentWindow)
console.info(Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow())
```

I hope it is output: demo or $.demo (if I don't give Id on this Window)
but I got that:

```
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.112] =====current_window=====
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.112]
[INFO] [iphone, 8.2, 192.168.1.112]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-currentWindow) says:

> This property is only available when using the Titanium.UI.Window.url property to load JavaScript files in their own contexts.

This property has been [removed](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-url) since 3.6.0/4.0.0 and has been deprecated for long.

You are supposed to use CommonJS (`require()` - **not** `Ti.include()`) to organise contexts and keep track of the current open window yourself, depending on how you manage your windows.